# Using webhook in flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, http, dart

I want to use webhooks in flutter. There is a website that I want to get live data from and listen to new events or data whenever they come, for example stocks live chart or like so. I searched almost everywhere and I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62937551/listening-to-api-changes-in-flutter) and also [here](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/flutter-dart/webhooks/) but I did not find what I wanted. Can you provide an example (with code) of using webhook in flutter or show me how can I achieve what I want? I'm really confused about this and how can I use it for my application.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can use github to implement web hooks...
Check [this documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/about-webhooks) for more information